# Will Ubuntu phones devices be available again

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, porting-ubuntu-touch

All BQ Aquaris devices with Ubuntu Touch are claimed unavailable from the [bq official website](https://store.bq.com/en/ubuntu-edition-e5). It says

```
"AVAILABILITY: OUT OF STOCK"
```

**Will there be additional stock soon or is this permanent?**

If permanent where can I find a BQ Aquaris from another place than the bq official site?

Comment: You could get this specific model with Android and install Ubuntu touch in it.

Comment: You may find them second hand on Ebay

Answer (score 3):

I also have been looking on the site and it says they are out of stock. If you look on the Ubuntu Devices page they say that “all our devices are currently sold out, but new devices will be coming soon”. So we can only hope that they will be here soon. If you sign up to the Devices Newsletter on this page you will get a clear idea of what is out there when it is released, [Ubuntu Device](https://www.ubuntu.com/phone/devices). Email BQ from their Contacts email address and ask them.